# Profiling clEnqueueWriteBuffer using clGetEventProfilingInfo

Tags: opencl

Is it possible to use the clGetEventProfilingInfo function to get the time taken by clEnqueueWriteBuffer function. I tried using it and i got the same values for CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START and CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END. I want to know whether this is because of some error in my code or because profiling wont work for clEnqueueWriteBuffer.

My code snippet is:

//Writing to input buffers

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue[0], buf_A, CL_TRUE, 0, PARTITION_SIZE * sizeof(int), input_A + (PARTITION_SIZE * j), 0, NULL, &eventList[0]);

checkErr(cl_err, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer : buf_A");

```
    clWaitForEvents(1, eventList);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[0], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(time_start_queued), &time_start_queued, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[0], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
    clGetEventProfilingInfo(eventList[0], CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
    total_time = ((double)time_end - time_start)/1000000;
    total_time_queued = ((double)time_end - time_start_queued)/1000000;
    final_time_data += total_time;
    final_time_queued_data += total_time_queued;
    cout<<"\nTime: "<<final_time_data<<" "<<final_time_queued_data;
```

And the output i get is:

Time : 0 0.288444

Since the value returned is 0 I am assuming its not able to find the time taken for data transfer.

Comment: Yes, this profiling API should work for any `clEnqueue*` command, so there's either a bug in the OpenCL runtime or a problem with your code. If you provide a code snippet we might be able to help.

Comment: How much data are you transfering? It could be that the data is so small that there is no time spend in the transfer. Also if the time falls inside the timer accuracy is may lead to a result of 0. Check the timer accuracy with CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION, usual values are between 1 and 500ns

Comment: Also, make sure your command queue was created with the CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE flag.

Comment: I have enabled the flag while creating the command queue. I am trying to transfer just 4MB of data.  Also I am using an ARM A10 APU. My understanding is that APU's have a unified memory for the GPU and CPU. So is it possible that the data is just being mapped to the GPU region and not being copied? I thought clEnqueueWriteBuffer always copied data. I am not sure. Please let me know if you have any idea about this. Thanks in advance